# I am unable to login after an update

Tags: login, login-screen

10th of June i've made an update and now I'm no more able to login. Unfortunately I don't know wat was included in this update. My PC looks like logging in, but, after a few seconds, it comes back to the login screen and ask me again and again the password (or to select another account).

Answer (score 0):

Try this for me:

When you boot up, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and attempt to log on using your local account, and see if that works.

If it does work, it may be that your password is somehow out of sync with the window manager that you're using, as seems to be the case in [this question.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/180669/user-password-rejected-on-login-screen-but-accepted-on-text-console-login?rq=1) Try doing the following, if you can log in:

```
sudo -i
[Enter your password]
passwd usr
```

Where usr is your username. Then, it should ask you for a new password, enter it in. Once you've done that type

```
reboot
```

And try to log back in once it's back to the screen.

If this doesn't work, please provide us this information:

1. Version of ubuntu (and flavor (e.g. xubuntu, kubuntu, etc))
2. What window manager you're using, if not the default for your flavor
3. If you're using compiz

Comment: I'll do that today afternoon (I have no access to my PC right now), but I have to note that I also have an account for my daughter with no password. Same behaviour. Seems to login and after few seconds it comes back to the login screen.

Comment: The result of executing your code didn't help. I uninstalled and reinstall lightdm, tried also with gdm, same situation. I have Ubuntu 14.04 TT, default window manager, I've uninstalled compiz.

Comment: Try following the instructions [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/223634/284690) and see if it helps

Comment: I tried, no result. Reinstalled 14.04 to solve.